# If statements in R-Markdown/R Console

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm having a difficult time trying to get my if statements to run for a code I am writing in which I am trying to analyze the number of true values per row for all of the rows in a sparse matrix (mat).

```
counter=0
geneCount=0
columnIndex=-1
cols=20
rows=20
for (col in 0:cols){
  columnIndex=columnIndex+1
  for (row in 0:rows){
    for (col in 0:cols){
      if (mat[row,col] = TRUE){
        counter=counter+1
      }
      if(counter = 2){
        sigArray[columnIndex]=sigArray[columnIndex]+1
        counter=0
        next
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I keep getting the error message:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"    for (col in 0:cols){
      if (mat[row,col] ="
```

for the first if statement. I have tried using double equals to and that didn't work either.

Thank you!

Comment: Try `==` instead. A single equal sign is interpreted as an assignment (like `counter = 0`).  Thought of using the `apply` function family instead?

Comment: Or just `if (mat[row,col]){` if your matrix is made up of logical elements. You might also use `if (isTRUE(mat[row,col])){` to be more conservative.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two problems. The first issue, as you thought, is that if statements are logical tests and thus need equality-testing operators. You need to use `==` to test for equality. The second issue is that R indices for rows and columns begin a 1, not zero. So, assuming you actually have 21 rows and columns in your dataset (i.e., such that 0 through 20 would have worked), I believe you should edit your syntax like this:

```
counter=0
geneCount=0
columnIndex=0
cols=21
rows=21
for (col in 1:cols){
  columnIndex=columnIndex+1
  for (row in 1:rows){
    for (col in 1:cols){
      if (mat[row,col] == TRUE){
        counter=counter+1
      }
      if(counter == 2){
        sigArray[columnIndex]=sigArray[columnIndex]+1
        counter=0
        next
      }
    }
  }
}
```